# Is data in Django’s request.POST object sanitised, at least enough for direct use in an ORM query?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I’m building a web forum using Django, including the [built-in authentication module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/).

I’m using the built-in [`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms) to register users. However, as I‘ve decided to use e-mail addresses as the sole way to identify users, I’m generating a username for users before registering them.

To account for users who have already registered, before I generate a username, I check that a user doesn’t exist with the supplied e-mail address.

Is it safe to use the supplied e-mail address, directly from `request.POST`, in a query to the Django ORM, without doing any sanitisation on it? I can’t see anything in the documentation about data in `request.POST` being sanitised, but [the ORM protects against SQL injection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection). Are there other potential attacks that I’m missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`request.POST` itself is not sanitized, but the Django ORM automatically sanitizes anything your throw at it, so yes, it's safe to simply pass it right to the ORM. Just be careful with using `raw` or `extra`.

Comment: Sure, I’m purely using it in one bog-standard ORM query, no dropping down into SQL.

Comment: Then, you have nothing to worry about.